# How to render a custom embeddable doctrine field using Twig?

Tags: doctrine, twig

I have a Doctrine entity which has a string field I'm trying to change into an embeddable to use a better abstraction.

I created the new class, changed the field type and then a template that used to render fine stopped working.

Here's the entity definition:

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;


/**
 * Security.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="security")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SecurityRepository")
 */
class Security
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="symbol", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @todo rename to ticker?
     */
    private ?string $symbol = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=9, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private ?CUSIP $cusip;

    /**
     * @return SecurityPrice
     */
    public function getPriceAt(DateTimeInterface $d): ?SecurityPrice
    {
        $foundPrices = $this->getPrices()->filter(fn(SecurityPrice $price) => $price->getDate() == $d);

        return !$foundPrices->isEmpty() ? $foundPrices->first() : null;
    }

    public function getCusip(): ?CUSIP
    {
        return $this->cusip;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCusip(?CUSIP $cusip): self
    {
        $this->cusip = $cusip;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->prices = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class CUSIP {
   private string $value;

   public function __construct(string $value) {
      if (strlen($value) < 9) {
          throw new InvalidCUSIP();
      }

      $this->value = $value;
   }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

This is what my twig template looks like:

```
                   {% for m in missing %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ m.getSecurity.getSymbol }}</td>
                            <td>{{ m.getSecurity.getCusip }}</td>
                            <td>{{ m.getSecurity.getIsin }}</td>
                            <td>{{ m.getSecurity.getDescription }}</td>
                            <td>{{ m.getSecurity.getSecurityType }}</td>
                            <td>{{ m.getDate|date('d-M-y') }}</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="price[{{ m.getId }}]" class="securityPrice"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

And the error I get is:

```
Typed property App\Entity\Security::$cusip must be an instance of App\Entity\CUSIP or null, string used
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my own question: I was missing an anotation along with the field definition.

When I changed it to:

```php
     /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class = "CUSIP")
     */
    private ?CUSIP $cusip = null;
```

It worked. Thanks!